# Validating the data in a tip calculator in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to get where when you don't enter a number or a letter in the box you get a pop-up box that said Please enter your number.

```
//converted a textbox into a decimal
Decimal enterNumber = Convert.ToDecimal(txtUserInput.Text);
// as well as vaidate the data
if (enterNumber<=0) {
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter your number");
}
```

ok when I try the tryParse I get an error on the return types not sure what the return keywords must not be followed by an object means

```
 decimal filler = 0m;


if (Decimal.TryParse(txtUserInput.Text, out filler))
        {
           //error
             return true;


        }
        // needs an else statment 
        else {
            MessageBox.Show("needs to be a number");
            txtUserInput.Focus();
           //error 
          return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think a standard approach is to just use, [`decimal.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73(v=vs.110).aspx) with the overloads for currency. This way you can check for valid currency input in your desired culture

> Converts the string representation of a number to its Decimal
>   equivalent using the specified style and culture-specific format. A
>   return value indicates whether the conversion succeeded or failed.

```
public static bool TryParse(
    string s,
    NumberStyles style,
    IFormatProvider provider,
    out decimal result
)
```

**Parameters**

- s `Type: System.String` The string representation of the number to convert.
- style `Type: System.Globalization.NumberStyles` A bitwise combination of enumeration values that indicates the permitted format of s. A typical value to specify is Number.
- provider `Type: System.IFormatProvider` An object that supplies culture-specific parsing information about s.
- result `Type: System.Decimal` When this method returns, contains the Decimal number that is equivalent to the numeric value contained in s, if the conversion succeeded, or is zero if the conversion failed. The conversion fails if the s parameter is null or String.Empty, is not in a format compliant with style, or represents a number less than MinValue or greater than MaxValue. This parameter is passed uninitialized; any value originally supplied in result will be overwritten.
- Return Value `Type: System.Boolean` true if s was converted successfully; otherwise, false.

**Exmaple**

```
// Parse currency value using en-GB culture.
value = "£1,097.63";
style = NumberStyles.Number | NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol;
culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB");
if (Decimal.TryParse(value, style, culture, out number))
   Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", value, number);
else
   Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert '{0}'.", value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a try-catch statement to find the right kind of input as well simple and gets the job done